# I increment pointer in function but he returns to previous position after exit from function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void func (char *data)
{
    data+=3;
    cout << data << "\n"; //456789
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    char * str = "123456789";
    char *data = str;
    func(data);
    cout << data << "\n"; // 123456789
    return 0;
}
```

Why this happend? Can't understand how it's possible. Can you explain, please?

Comment: You are incrementing a **copy** of the pointer.

Comment: This happens for the same reason that `void f(int x) { x += 3; } int main() { int a = 0; f(a); std::cout << a; }` outputs `0`, not `3`. There's nothing special about pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass variables to functions they are passed *by value*, what that means is that the value of the variable is *copied* to the argument variable. And as you only modify a copy in the function, the original variable will not be modified.

To pass the actual original value you need to pass it by reference. This is done by using the ampersand when declaring the argument:

```
void func (char *&data)
```

Comment: or by pointer.....to pointer, man should know the difference to.

Comment: This is the best answer, as passing by reference also forces char* to not be null.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. Initially you fell (after me) in the trap of thinking like C, but this is C++. Bravo. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a double pointer like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void func (char **data)
{
    if(!*data) return;
    (*data)+=3;
    cout << (*data) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    char * str = "123456789";
    char *data = str;
    func(&data);
    cout << data << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However, since this is C++, I strongly suggest you to use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

I even get a warning for `str`:

`deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`

In order to git rid of that warning, you should use `char const *str`, but then you can't continue with what you do.

---

The reason your code did not work, is that the argument is passed by value, thus it does not get modified.

Answer (score -1):

You are modifing local copy of pointer. You would need to pass pointer to that pointer to be able to modify it.

```
void func (char **data)
{
    *data += 3;
}
```

Comment: If this was 1980 C, yes.  But OP stated C++, so a reference to a pointer is a better answer.  For example, what if data was NULL?  Your solution would fault.  Adding a check for non-NULL is not even needed if the function requires a reference to a pointer.

Comment: I completely agree with you :)